# What would be a efficient way of Storing an XML to oracle tables parent child

Tags: xml, oracle

What would be an efficient way of storing a XML to Oracle tables parent child

My tables are order_header and order_item. Against one header there can be many items.

The structure of my XML is

```
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <CODE>1000385</CODE>
  <ORDER_ITEMS>
   <ORDER_ITEM>
    <ES_ORDER_HEADER__CODE>1000385</ES_ORDER_HEADER__CODE>
    <QUANTITY_SHIPPED>0</QUANTITY_SHIPPED>
    <ITEM_NUMBER>1</ITEM_NUMBER>
   </ORDER_ITEM>
   <ORDER_ITEM>
    <ES_ORDER_HEADER__CODE>1000385</ES_ORDER_HEADER__CODE>
    <QUANTITY_SHIPPED>0</QUANTITY_SHIPPED>
    <ITEM_NUMBER>2</ITEM_NUMBER>
   </ORDER_ITEM>
  </ORDER_ITEMS>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

In Step 1 I have generated this XML. Now the requirement is to save the same xml in the two tables.

Comment: if you're using 11gR2 the see http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/tip/Oracle-XML-capabilities-in-Oracle-Database-11gR2-part-3, else see http://oracleappsa2z.blogspot.com/2011/09/multilevel-xml-to-multiple-table.html

Comment: This XML looks like it was created with DBMS_XMLGEN?  If your source and destination are both Oracle tables then there are probably easier ways to do this (that is, without using XML).

Comment: Thanks A.B Cade for the inputs , the link one appears more clean than link 2 , i will evaluate these and come back.

Comment: Hello jonearles, this xml is supposed to flow between two systems .The the final source and destination is our system but it flows across other systems, so has to be like that.

Comment: Also ,i am evaluating inserting data from xml to nested trables and then manuplating data through normal cursors and looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blogpost of mine describes how to do it in SQL only (read: most efficient way):

http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2010/03/shredding-xml-into-multiple-tables-in.html

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Rob , i will evaluate this also.Regards abhi

Comment: More the suggestions , more the knowledge gained from this thread

Comment: I have opted for the approach         http://oracleappsa2z.blogspot.in/2011/09/multilevel-xml-to-multiple-table.html ,                                                     but was wondering why t is being selected with t2               "FROM t t, TABLE (xmlsequence (t.xml.extract ('EMP_ROWS/EMP'))) t2" , where t is the xmltype .containing whole document

Comment: Because that author is unaware that version 10 introduced the much more convenient XMLTable, instead of TABLE(XMLSequence()). It also forces you to repeated state the namespace when extracting individual elements. And you can use the method from that blog, because you are in luck with the repeating ORDER_HEADER_CODES, which allows easy linking of master with detail. You should use my approach if you have an XML where the detail doesn't contain an ORDER_HEADER_CODE.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable inputs Regards abhi

Comment: Another nice article on XML processing http://martin-mares.com/2010/08/oracle-db-how-to-processing-xml-with-multiple-nodes-xmlsequence/ , once you have an xml in form of a table you can insert into a GTT or a temporary table or user types and play with it like anything   , enjoy ! Thanks Abhi

Comment: i think the approach has nothing to do with ORDER_HEADER_CODES linking of master  with details , because the author is only taking the data from the outer parents , then the table of inner children and then making them union all , that can be achieved with the xmltable also

Comment: That's right, XMLTable can do that as well. My approach, using guid's and analytic functions, is needed when you don't have a linking attribute like ORDER_HEADER_CODES. When the relationship is dictated by just the place in the XML. Hope that makes it more clear.